# Characterization of "PSD-Squared" Matrices

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

$\DeclareMathOperator\DNN{DNN}\DeclareMathOperator\CP{CP}$This question can be thought of as an offshoot of [this MO question from a few months ago](https://mathoverflow.net/q/353849/11236). Let $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ denote the set of $n \times n$ complex matrices. Whenever I refer to positive semidefinite (PSD) matrices, I assume they are Hermitian. I use "$\odot$" to refer to the [entrywise/Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) of matrices, and I will shortly take the (entrywise) complex conjugate of a matrix.

**Vague question:** What can be said about the set $S$ of matrices
$$
S \mathrel{:=} \{ X \odot \overline{X} : \text{$X \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is positive semidefinite}\}?
$$

**Some observations:** Every member of $S$ is clearly real and entrywise non-negative, and the solution to [the MO question linked above](https://mathoverflow.net/q/353849/11236) shows that every member of $S$ is positive semidefinite. We thus have $S \subseteq \DNN$, where $\DNN$ is the set of [doubly nonnegative matrices](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoublyNonnegativeMatrix.html).

**Precise question #1:** Does $S = \DNN$?

If the answer to "precise question #1" is "no", several natural follow-up questions arise. For example, the most well-known set of matrices that is contained within $\DNN$ is the set $\CP$ of [completely positive matrices](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompletelyPositiveMatrix.html). This leads to …

**Precise question #2:** Does $S = \CP$?

In fact, it's not clear to me that $S \subseteq \CP$ or $\CP \subseteq S$, so either of those inclusions (or refutations of those inclusions) would be interesting as well.